# I get IndexError while still in the range

Tags: python, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read the rows of a csv file. My file looks like this

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col3
row11, row12, row13
row21, row22, row23
row31, row32, row33
...
```

I use the following command to read the rows

```
with open('~/data.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in range(5):
        print(list(r)[i])
```

The output prints the first row, but then it give the out of index error right after.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-efcc4f8c760d> in <module>()
      2     r = csv.DictReader(f)
      3     for i in range(5):
----> 4         print(list(r)[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm guessing I'm making a silly mistake somewhere, but can't spot it. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** This is the output of `print(list(r))`:

```
[{'Col 1': 'row11', ' Col3': ' row13', ' Col 2': ' row12'}, {'Col 1': 'row21', ' Col3': ' row23', ' Col 2': ' row22'}, {'Col 1': 'row31', ' Col3': ' row33', ' Col 2': ' row32'}, {'Col 1': 'row41', ' Col3': ' row43', ' Col 2': ' row42'}, {'Col 1': 'row51', ' Col3': ' row53', ' Col 2': ' row52'}, {'Col 1': 'row61', ' Col3': ' row63', ' Col 2': ' row62'}, {'Col 1': 'row71', ' Col3': ' row73', ' Col 2': ' row72'}, {'Col 1': 'row81', ' Col3': ' row83', ' Col 2': ' row82'}, {'Col 1': 'row91', ' Col3': ' row93', ' Col 2': ' row92'}, {'Col 1': 'row101', ' Col3': ' row103', ' Col 2': ' row102'}]
```

Comment: What does `print(list(r))` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DictReader(f)` just gives you a one time look at your file -- you can only call `list` on it once, but you call it multiple times because it's within the loop. Later calls return an empty `list`. Just call `list` on it outside of the loop and save it in a variable, and you'll be golden.

That is:

```
r = csv.DictReader(f)
rows = list(r)
for i in range(5):
    print(rows[i])
```

Or, don't pull the whole thing into memory at any point:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    print row
```

If you'd like to keep the index around for other purposes:

```
 for i, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(f)):
     print i, row
```

If you want to get specific rows from an `iterator` (which `csv.DictReader` is a special case of) without pulling the whole thing into memory, check out `itertools.islice` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html. It basically allows `list`-style slicing on an `iterator`.

```
  # prints first five rows
  for row in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(f), 5):
       print row
```

For more sporadic rows:

```
  needed_row_indices = {2, 5, 20}
  for i, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(f)):
      if i in needed_row_indices:
          print row
```

Comment: Thank you very much, while that works for a small example, my problem is that I am working with a big data set, about 10Gb. Any idea on how to avoid loading the whole thing?

Comment: Updated to show how you can avoid pulling the whole thing into memory. @Keivan

Comment: Thank you again. Would you happen to have some idea on how to read several specific rows of the file this way? That was originally my question and I was trying to simplify it, so I got to this point. This solve my question asked above though.

Comment: @Keivan check out `itertools`, which I explain a little in the post.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. It still have some problems though, it seems like it reads the rows and adds up the index. Basically I need to read for example line 2, then line 5, then line 20, and so on in the file, and I am finding these 2,5,20 etc by some calculations, can I call them directly somehow?

Comment: @Keivan, if the rows you need are more sporadically distributed like that, I would suggest you a) build a set of the rows you need -- for example, `needed_rows = {2, 5, 20}` -- and then b) use the above example with `enumerate` but only act on the row when `i in needed_rows`

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. For some reason I was trying to avoid making a new list, probably because I was afraid of it getting too big, but what you say makes sense. I'll do that. Thanks again.

Comment: I mean, if there's a formula or other function that can serve as the test, you can of course use that instead of the set membership -- but if it's basically a hardcoded set of randomly distributed rows, not sure how much better you can do.

Comment: Yes, it's basically random, I find these row numbers in a data set, and then have to find corresponding data to those rows in the second data set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74897/discussion-between-keivan-and-jwilner).