# How to read specific lines of a large csv file

Tags: python, csv, large-files

I am trying to read some specific rows of a large csv file, and I don't want to load the whole file into memory. The index of the specific rows are given in a list `L = [2, 5, 15, 98, ...]` and my csv file looks like this:

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col3
row11, row12, row13
row21, row22, row23
row31, row32, row33
...
```

Using the ideas mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553989/i-get-indexerror-while-still-in-the-range) I use the following command to read the rows

```
with open('~/file.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f) # I need to read it as a dictionary for my purpose

    for i in L:
        for row in enumerate(r):
            print row[i]
```

I immediately get the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-78951a0d4937> in <module>()
      6     for i in L:
      7         for row in enumerate(r):
----> 8             print row[i]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**Question 1.** It seems like my use of the `for` loops here is obviously wrong. Any ideas on how to fix this?

On the other hand, the following gets the job done, but it's too slow:

```
def read_csv_line(line_number):
    with open("~/file.csv") as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        for i, line in enumerate(r):
            if i == (line_number - 2):
                return line
    return None

for i in L:
    print read_csv_line(i)
```

**Question 2.** Any idea on how to improve this basic method of going through the whole file until I reach row i then print it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A file doesn't have "lines" or "rows". What you consider a "line" is "what is found between two *newline* characters". As such you cannot read the nth line without reading the lines before it, as you couldn't count the newline characters.

**Answer 1**: if you consider your example, but with L=[9], unrolling your loops would give:

```
i=9
row = (0, {'Col 2': 'row12', 'Col 3': 'row13', 'Col 1': 'row11'})
```

As you can see, row is a tuple with two members, calling `row[i]` means `row[9]`, hence the IndexError.

**Answer 2**: This is very slow because you are reading the file up to the line number every time. In your example, you read the first 2 lines, then the first 5, then the first 15,  then the first 98, etc. So you've read the first 5 lines 3 times. You could create a generator that only returns the lines you want (beware, line numbers would be 0-indexed):

```
def read_my_lines(csv_reader, lines_list):
    for line_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if line_number in lines_list:
            yield line_number, row
```

So when you want to process the lines, you would do:

```
L = [2, 5, 15, 98, ...]
with open('~/file.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line_number, line in read_my_lines(r, L):
        do_something_with_line(line)
```

*** *Edit* ***

This could further be improved to stop reading the file when you've read all the lines you wanted:

```
def read_my_lines(csv_reader, lines_list):
    # make sure every line number shows up only once:
    lines_set = set(lines_list)
    for line_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if line_number in lines_set:
            yield line_number, row
            lines_set.remove(line_number)
            # Stop when the set is empty
            if not lines_set:
                raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `L` is a list containing the line numbers you want, you could do :

```
with open("~/file.csv") as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i, line in enumerate(r):
        if i in L:    # or (i+2) in L: from your second example
            print line
```

That way :

- you read the file only once
- you do not load the whole file in memory
- you only get the lines you are interested in

The only caveat is that you read whole file even if `L = [3]`

Comment: Thanks, I finally ended up doing something similar to this. The catch was that my list L was already ordered, and I didn't really need to check membership each time. I only checked if `i == L[0]`, and then omitted the first entry of `L`. To avoid reading the whole file @vlad has given a solution, above.

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in enumerate(r):
```

will pull tuples. You are then trying to select your ith element from a 2 element tuple.

for example

```
>> for i in enumerate({"a":1, "b":2}): print i
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
```

Additionally, since dictionaries are hash tables, your initial order is not necessarily preserved. for instance:

```
>>list({"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":5})
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to sum up the great ideas, I ended up using something like this: `L` can be sorted relatively quickly, and in my case it was actually already sorted. So, instead of several membership checks in `L` it pays off to sort it and then only check each index against the first entry of it. Here is my piece of code:

```
count=0
with open('~/file.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in r:
        count += 1
        if L == []:
            break
        elif count == L[0]:
            print (row)
            L.pop(0)
```

Note that this stops as soon as we've gone through `L` once.