# How to read a few lines in a large CSV file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that doesn't fit into my system's memory. Using Pandas, I want to read a small number of rows scattered all over the file.

I think that I can accomplish this without pandas following the steps here: [How to read specific lines of a large csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567023/how-to-read-specific-lines-of-a-large-csv-file)

In pandas, I am trying to use skiprows to select only the rows that I need.

```
# FILESIZE is the number of lines in the CSV file (~600M)
# rows2keep is an np.array with the line numbers that I want to read (~20)

rows2skip = (row for row in range(0,FILESIZE) if row not in rows2keep)
signal = pd.read_csv('train.csv', skiprows=rows2skip)
```

I would expect this code to return a small dataframe pretty fast. However, what is does is start consuming memory over several minutes until the system becomes irresponsive. I'm guessing that it is reading the whole dataframe first and will get rid of rows2skip later.

Why is this implementation so inefficient? How can I efficiently create a dataframe with only the lines specified in rows2keep?

Comment: Did you try reading data in chunks with `chunksize`?

Comment: Also try `modlin` in `pandas`. Heard it quite fast it reading large dataset!!

Comment: Hey @RahulAgarwal, what is modlin? Never heard of it.

Comment: it is new way of making your pandas read faster...just google it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
train = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=150000)
```

If you only want to read the first n rows:

```
train = pd.read_csv(..., nrows=n)
```

If you only want to read rows from n to n+100

```
train = pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=n, nrows=n+100)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I am trying next :) But now I still need to filter the rows in the chunks somehow. I was wondering whether there is a more direct way?

Comment: What i mean is  apply the same rows2skip function to chunks i.e., train = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=150000, skiprows=rows2skip)

Comment: I would expect this to work (a mixture of chunksize and skiprows), but it doesn't - it clogs memory the same. It seems that pandas is still somehow trying to load everything at once if we specify any rows to skip.

Answer (score 0):

`chunksize` should help in limiting the memory usage. Alternatively, if you only need a few number of lines, a possible way is to first read the required lines ouside of pandas and then only feed `read_csv` with that subset. Code could be:

```
lines = [line for i, line in enumerate(open('train.csv')) if i in lines_to_keep]
signal = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''.join(lines)))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good idea, but the reading takes incredibly long.